# dashboard cannot login with admin account

Tags: openstack

After I installed the dashboard on 2 Ubuntu16 nodes, I can login the web page dashboard.
All the instructions is followed from

https://docs.openstack.org/project-install-guide/ocata/ubuntu-services.html 
nova-manage ---version===15.0.1
keystone is already the newest version (2:11.0.0-0ubuntu1.1~cloud0)

Checking on apache error log is like this:
[wsgi:error] [pid 21177:tid 140685076526848] Login failed for user "admin", remote address x.x.x.x
[wsgi:error] [pid 21177:tid 140685076526848] Login failed for user "admin", remote address x.x.x.x

There were plenty of this error after freshing web page.
I didn't change admin account password, when I check openstack status, like openstack user list, etc. It will show the directly result.
In my case, I believe the keystone service is working, for dashborad is granted all host visit.

ps -ef|grep keystone
root     16785 16296  0 16:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto keystone
keystone 21178 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-pu -k start
keystone 21179 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-pu -k start
keystone 21180 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-pu -k start
keystone 21181 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-pu -k start
keystone 21182 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-pu -k start
keystone 21183 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-ad -k start
keystone 21184 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-ad -k start
keystone 21185 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-ad -k start
keystone 21186 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-ad -k start
keystone 21187 21172  0 09:32 ?        00:00:02 (wsgi:keystone-ad -k start

So I got 2 concerns:
1. how to fix it :)
2 I found after sync with keystone local database, I found it can't find keystone service, which I can't restart it both /etc/init.d/keystone (cannot find keystone service name) and systemctl restart keystone(no keytone).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ocata.

Please try to restart below services:

```
systemctl restart mariadb.service httpd.service memcached.service
```

After restart DB I got access to log in for a first time.

Comment: thanks for your reply, trying it , it seems the mariadb.service cannot be seen, memcache and apache2 I've already restart it, the platform are Ubuntu16.04.
This is wired, I also can't not find keystone, I mean I cannot find keystone.
Given the feedback below:
Failed to restart mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.